# API mocking for websocket (in React)

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io, mocking, msw

I am currently working on a frontend-only React project. It is a file explorer similar to Google Drive, designed for usage by multiple users. To enable real-time communication, I would like to incorporate a websocket. However, I do not wish to create a separate backend to handle the API connection.

I attempted to use the library available at https://github.com/mswjs/socket.io-binding, but encountered a 404 error when trying to install the **@mswjs/socket.io-binding** package using npm.

Is there any solution available to mock a websocket server in a production environment?